# Using NLTK RegexpParser to find subject, object, verb combinations

Tags: nltk

I'm trying to extract subject object verb combinations using the NLTK tool kit. This is my code so far. How would I be able to do it?

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

grammar = r"""
  NP:
    {<.*>+}          # Chunk everything
    }<VBD|VBZ|VBP|IN>+{      # Chink sequences of VBD and IN
  """
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
s = "This song is the best song in the world. I really love it."
for t in sent_tokenize(s):
    text = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(t))
    print cp.parse(text)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @user. Unfortunately your question is way too broad to allow a reasonable answer. Read or think about your task a little more, and come back with a more specific question when you have gotten a little further.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can try is to chunk the sentences in NPs (noun phrases) and VPs (verb phrases) and then build a RBS (Rule Based System) on top of this to establish the chunk roles. For example if the VP is in ActiveVoice then the Subject should be the chunk in front of the VP. If it's in PassiveVoice it should be the following NP.

You can also have a look at Pattern.en . The parser has Relation Extraction included: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#parser